# Change Node Owner On Node Submit

Tags: nodes, forms

How can I change the owner of an anonymously submitted node upon the initial node creation?

Goal:

1. Anonymous user completes form.
2. Node owner is changed to a specific user id.
3. Node is inserted into DB.

Can this be done with `hook_form_FORM_ID_alter();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[hook_form_FORM_ID_alter](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_form_FORM_ID_alter/7) is used to alter the form before it is rendered, if you want to alter the form after being submitted and before being save, you have to use [hook_node_presave](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.api.php/function/hook_node_presave/7).
Put this code in a `custom.module`:

```
function custom_node_presave($node) {
  if ($node->uid == 0) {
    // Change anonymous node author to uid: 2
    $node->uid = 2;
  }
}
```